# Glitch when opening app on Ubuntu 20.04.03

Tags: 20.04, display

I installed Ubuntu 20.04.02 and then updated it to 20.04.03 from terminal emulator. Everything went well but [this happened.](https://youtu.be/UuCwCSlbW5c) Everytime I open a new instance app, the UI elements will be transparent until I move the window. This happened to all apps. Windows 11 and previosly installed Kubuntu don't have this problem. Ubuntu 20.04.02 has this problem but very rarely, the .03 just happens all the time.

For additional info, I run Ubuntu on mechanical hard drive, i5-10210U, 12 GB of RAM, MX 250 have tried all version of proprietary driver and open source driver.

I do not want to fully reinstall it because it costs a LOT of money to use Internet bandwidth in my country and I have really tailored this particular installation to my liking :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's fixed 
The extension "Blur My Shell" caused the problem
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3193/blur-my-shell/

Comment: Feel free to "accept" your own answer: shows people clearly that this was solved.